# addAnnotation crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, crash, mkmapview

I have crash in my project. I use MKMapView and sometimes it crashes in addAnnotation(s) method.

I get message from XCode that crash stating

```
method _insert(objc_object*, MKQuadTrieNode*, MKQuadTrie*)
```

Please, help me.

please see  the below image [image: http://cl.ly/image/0y2U1p052E3l]

P.S. Crash is reproduced not always. It is reproduced after 100+ annotations, sometimes after 300 or 500+. This objects are returns from server and I check coordinate for it.

Comment: put your add annotation code...

Answer (score 0):

Enable Zombies in your project.

Press <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd><</kbd> and select **Enable Zombie Object** in **Diagnostic** tab.

Now your are able to see what's wrong.

hope this help.

Comment: I haven't zombie object. I checked it.

Comment: Impossible. Go in RUN->Diagnostic in the "Edit scheme..." section. Press CMD+< or go in menu Product->Scheme->Edit scheme

Comment: I know it. Zombie object is enabled.